# How to specify a certain coordinator nodes list in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a Cassandra cluster with 12 nodes. I want to have 9 nodes for storing the data and 3 nodes which will just act like coordinator nodes without storing any data.
How can I force the driver to choose the coordinator nodes that I want?

I am using Cassandra 3.1.5, Spring boot with Cassandra auto-config and Spring data

Answer (score 0):

You can create coordinator only node by mentioning `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.join_ring=false"` in cassandra env file.

Now at driver level you just need to specify 3 coordinator as contact list

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that way but I got a warning that
`2020-02-04 10:32:22.114  WARN 3152 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : You listed <myhost>:9042 in your contact points, but it wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup
` with 2 of 3 nodes.
Then I tried to inspect the connection and found that just 1 of 3 coordinators is connected by the driver. What gives?